# Restrict a Load-Balanced Google backend bucket to a specific IP range

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google Storage bucket that I want to make accessible (anonymous, read-only) to a specific set of internet IP's (whitelist)

I can expose the bucket with a [load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-bucket#using_a_cloud_storage_bucket_as_a_load_balancer_backend), but I have not been able to find a way to apply any firewall/IP rules to it.

A [Cloud Armor policy](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies#enabling_ip_blacklistwhitelist_for_https_load_balancing) can only be applied to `backend services` not `backend buckets`.

And the GCP firewall rules only apply to virtual instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any option to do this specific ask as of yet. GCS buckets are mainly controlled through ACLs. However, with Cloud Armor in Beta, this would be a perfect time for a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to include backend buckets as targets.